# setEditorState is missing one last typed character

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am not getting the last typed character from the editor. Here is the code.

```
const onEditorStateChanged = (editor) => {
    setEditorState(editor)
    props.giveMeTextOnly(editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText())
    props.onStateChange(
        draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent())),
    )
}

<Editor
    editorState={editorState}
    onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChanged}
    // onContentStateChange={onContentStateChange}
    editorStyle={{ padding: '0 20px' }}
    placeholder="Type here..."
/>
```

I don't think we need a callback or some type of wait for the state of the editor in this case.
What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to delete the question after I solved it but it might help you too.

Yes, we need to wait for setting the editor state. Used useEffect hook, listening for change in the editor state like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.giveMeTextOnly(editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText())
    props.onStateChange(
        draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent())),
    )
}, [editorState])

const onEditorStateChanged = editor => {
    setEditorState(editor)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

beacuse editorState does not update right away, so do not use eidtorState to get text, use editor, it is the latest.

```
const onEditorStateChanged = (editor) => {
setEditorState(editor)
props.giveMeTextOnly(editor.getCurrentContent().getPlainText())
props.onStateChange(
    draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent())),
)
```

}